# Docusign createEnvelope only populating tab fields that have initial values

Tags: node.js, docusignapi

I am using the Docusign node sdk to `createEnvelope` from different templates on our DS instance. For some reason only the fields that have initial values will get populated by the sdk. There are no duplicates of data label values.

Here is my request:

```
const envelopesApi = new docusign.EnvelopesApi();
const envelopeDef = {
  "customFields": {
    "textCustomFields": [
      { "name": "Opportunity ID", "value": "12345" }
    ]
  },
  "status": "sent",
  "templateId": "[templateId]",
  "templateRoles": [
    {
      "email": "bob@email.com",
      "name": "Bob",
      "roleName": "Signer 2",
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Contract - Contract Signer",
            "value": "Bob"
          },
          { "tabLabel": "Contract - Phone", "value": "5554443333" },
          { "tabLabel": "Contract - Value", "value": "0" }
        ]
      }
    },
    {
      "email": "bill@email.com",
      "name": "Bill",
      "roleName": "Signer 1",
      "tabs": {
        "textTabs": [
          {
            "tabLabel": "Contract - Contract Signer",
            "value": "Bill"
          },
          { "tabLabel": "Contract - Phone", "value": "5554443333" },
          { "tabLabel": "Contract - Value", "value": "0" }
        ]
      }
    }
  ]
};

envelopesApi.createEnvelope(accountId, envelopeDef, cb);
```

If I edit any of the fields on the template to have an initial value, they get populated upon envelopeCreation, and if I leave the initial value blank, they don't get populated.

The fields we are using on our templates are merge fields that use our SalesForce connection. I imagine that might make a difference because I don't get the same behavior on regular custom text fields.

I can pre populate the templates with initial values before creating an envelope, but I would rather not have to do that if possible.

Comment: I think the issue is that you should use composite templates to add initial values to the template. Search the StackOverflow questions marked with tag **docusigncompositetmplts** (I'm sorry that I don't know more and thus can't give you a more specific answer.) If you find the answer, please answer your own question with the solution.

Comment: Turns out this was a simple problem. I was under the impression that the templates I was working with had all unique fields, but there were in fact duplicate fields with the same data label. So when they weren't initialized, the duplicate fields will not populate without the prefix `\\*` on the tabLabel. Adding that prefix allows everything to populate as expected